# Which preposition to be used here

Tags: prepositions

> I bought this from market
>   I bought this by market

"From market" sounds idiomatic. But what would by market mean?

Comment: Where did you find the second sentence?

Answer (score 3):

"By market" would mean "by means of a market" or "using the device of a market" and would not, ordinarily make sense.  Even if it sounds logical, there is no context I can think of in which "I used a market to buy this" would feel idiomatically correct.

You can use "buy by X" to describe the *method* or *measure* of how something is normally bought:

> Gasoline is normally bought *by volume*, not *by weight*.
>
> Large orders of beef can be bought *by grade*.

However, even with this it would be more common to say "sold by" or "priced by" and not "bought by".

> Gasoline/petrol is sold *by volume*
>
> Meat is priced *by grade*.

If you want to say that a market is normally where or how to buy something, you would say something like:

> You can buy it *at* the market.
>
> You have to buy it *at* the market price, which changes daily.
>
> Shares in publicly traded companies are bought *on* the (stock) market.

Or, in some cases, you could say:

> (Some special item) can only be bought *through* the (some special) market.

Side note: "from market" is not idiomatic in American English.  We almost always say "from *the* market".  However, this is idiomatic, not grammatical, since we do say "from school", "from church", "from class", "from home" and various others.